# when child element has only :focus-visible, how to get parent element :focus-within?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, focus

When a child element has only focus-visible, how to get parent parent element focus-within?

I want the parent get outline when focus child by keyboard.
But this code is always has focus(outline) when I click to label or checkbox.

How can I do this?
I'm trying

```
.parent:focus-within:not(:focus){ ~~ }
```

but it failed.

This is my code:

```css
.parent:focus-within {
    outline: red auto 1px;
}
.child:focus {
    outline-color: red;
}
.child:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<label class="parent">
  <input type="checkbox" class="child">
</label>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is behavior is [not supported by `:focus-within`](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3080), but it is possible using [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

```css
.parent:has(:focus-visible) {
  outline: red auto 1px;
}

.child:focus {
  outline-color: red;
}

.child:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<label class="parent">
  <input type="checkbox" class="child">
</label>
</pre>
```

[`:has()` browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas())